# How does this c++ implementation of bead sort algorithm work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have been trying to understand this code for hours unsuccessfully. I wrote my own version of bead sort algorithm however it is so slow.
I want to understand why this one works so much more quickly.
Here's info about the bead sort algorithm:
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ExtendedBeadSort/
Can you please help me to understand how this algorithm works?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

void distribute(int dist, vector<int> &List) {
    //*beads* go down into different buckets using gravity (addition).
    if (dist > List.size() )
        List.resize(dist); //resize if too big for current vector

    for (int i=0; i < dist; i++)
        List[i]++;
}

vector<int> beadSort(int *myints, int n) {
    vector<int> list, list2, fifth (myints, myints + n);
    cout << "sakums\n";
    cout << myints<< "\n";
 //   for (vector<int>::iterator it = fifth.begin(); it != fifth.end(); ++it) cout << " " << *it << "\n";
    cout << "beigas\n";

    cout << "#1 Beads falling down: ";
    for (int i=0; i < fifth.size(); i++)
        distribute (fifth[i], list);
    cout << '\n';

    cout << "\nBeads on their sides: ";
    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
        cout << " " << list[i];
    cout << '\n';

    //second part

    cout << "#2 Beads right side up: ";
    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
        distribute (list[i], list2);
    cout << '\n';

    return list2;
}

int main() {
    int myints[] = {734,3,1,24,324,324,32,432,42,3,4,1,1};
    vector<int> sorted = beadSort(myints, sizeof(myints)/sizeof(int));
    cout << "Sorted list/array";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<sorted.size(); i++)
        cout << sorted[i] << ' ';
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be a waste of time to suggest a debugger - nothing would compre to you seeing how it works rather than being told...

Comment: @John: Do you know how the [bead sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead_sort) works in general?

Comment: Maybe a better way would be to post your implementation and then ask why it is slow?

Comment: i understand why my implementation is slow. i wanted to understand why this works faster

Comment: Because of how distribute works, it "distributes" beads in "columns" I.e when you print it on its side, there are now 734 slots - the largest number. Each of the other numbers contribute "beads" to the slots - there are 13 numbers so slot 1 has 13  in it when it finishes - when distribute runs again it shifts the "beads" down by summing the column - it will perform a number of additions dependent on the max element *2 - plus memory allocations

Comment: @John: This is the most obvious implementation I can think of.  If it's faster than yours, that must be because you did something slow in your version.  I can't tell you why this is faster, because this is really the only way to do it.  Actually, how do you know that this is faster, and by how much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how distribute works:

Each of the other numbers contribute "beads" to the slots - there are 13 numbers so slot 1 has 13  in it when it finishes the first pass.

it "distributes" beads in "columns" I.e when you print it on its side, there are now 734 slots - the largest number.

When distribute runs again it shifts the "beads" down by summing the columns - it will perform a number of additions dependent on the max element * The number of numbers - plus memory allocations

Answer (score 1):

Its my implementation! I am the original author for the bead sort in C++ that you see on rosettacode.

The reason that the algorithm is so slow is because this sort has three major slowdown issues. One deals with the potential resize of the vector every time distribute runs O(S). This also is combined with the actual adding of the numbers one by one down each "pole" O(S)+O(S) or O(2S) and then doing this n times where n is the numbers to be sorted O(n)+O(2S). Since S is still larger in most cases, the algorithm is still O(S).

To be fair, all it will take is someone making a better implementation and less verbose version of my code to improve performance. I made this algorithm this way to showcase as easily as possible for people new to bead sort.

Also check the wiki page of bead sort if you wish to learn more about it.